# How to downsample a dataset with constraints in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, sampling, dataset

I have a dataset that has columns `a`, `b`, and others. Both `a` and `b` are numerical values, for example,

```
       a b c d e ...
row_0  2 5 .....
row_1  6 3 .....
...
```

I am hoping to downsample the dataset from total rows `n` to `n_d`, while changing the ratio of `sum(a)/sum(b)` to a given value, e.g., `sum(a_d)/sum(b_d) = 1.5`. Is there a package or method I could use to achieve this goal?

Comment: Not sure what the connection is to machine learning or mathematical statistics. Are you sure those are appropriate tags?

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud here. You want
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n_d}a_j&=1.5\sum_{j=1}^{n_d}b_j\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n_d}(a_j-1.5b_j)&=0\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n_d}\tilde{a}_j&=0,
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{a}_j=a_j-1.5b_j.$ On the face of it, this could be a very large problem. It depends on the size of your data. For each row, you can include it or not. So that means you have $2^n$ possible subsets. If $n$ is not too large, you could simply calculate the $\tilde{a}_j$ column, then run through all $2^n$ possible combinations, and see which one minimizes
$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n_d}\tilde{a}_j\right|.$$
But this will be intractable very quickly.

What you have here, is essentially the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), an area of research. You can check the link for more, possibly more efficient algorithms.